# Is pinning a custom CA certificate enough to verify last certificate in the chain?

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, socketrocket

I am trying to use a custom CA on SocketRocket.
Is pinning the root certificate enough to verify `MySuperServer` in the construct below?

```
-MyCustomCA
 -IntermadiateA
  -IntermadiateA1
   -MySuperServer
```

Or do I have to pin `IntermadiateA1` certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinning of the root certificate worked for me.

Comment: 3-months-hard question huh?

Comment: 3 months ago I don't even know objective-c. ;-)